# Create a location for Visual Studio code snippets

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-snippets

This is similar to [How to move Visual Studio's 'My Code Snippets' folder to another drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478406/how-to-move-visual-studios-my-code-snippets-folder-to-another-drive), but the answer there is quite old and does not seem to work any more; furthermore, the relevant paths appear to have changed.

I created a code snippet via the VS snippets manager. It worked, but I wanted to change the shortcut. I couldn't see a way to delete the individual snippet in their UI, so I deleted the folder as it contained just that snippet. I am now finding myself unable to create a folder for my C# snippets.

When I go to save the snippet, I now see this window. The only option obviously makes no sense, and doesn't work in any case:
[image]

I've tried the "add" button in their UI. I am sometimes able to add a folder that way.

[image]But if I do, the import still fails:

[image]

Given that I deleted the folder where the snippets were formerly located, how can I get snippet import to work?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work by renaming the file to the same name as one of the snippets at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#
```

I then moved the file to that location, giving admin permission when it asked. This seems frankly absurd. But it did work, for a while; at some point VS reset the snippet.