# Visual Studio: Is it safe to delete "My code snippets" folders?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

After installing Visual Studio 2019 on my windows machine I discovered a new subfolder named "Visual Studio 2019" under my home folder -C:\Users\zack.  inside that vs folder there are three subfolders: `Templetes\ItemTemplets`, `Templates\ProjectTemplets` and `Code Snippets`. They have some other subfolders to them, but no files.

I don't know what was supposed to be stored there. I save my coding projects under `C:\Projects` and my libraries under C:\SDK. Why shouldn't I delete `C:\Users\zack\Visual Studio 2019`?

Answer (score 1):

If you create custom code snippets (or download any from the Internet) you can place the files containing those there.  I have been creating my own snippets for a while and then when I update my version of Visual Studio, I just need to copy the folder from the older version to the newer version.

It should be safe to delete the folder if you have never created any personal snippets.  It wouldn't surprise me though if an update to your Visual Studio install brought it back.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: But again, if I will delete that subfolder, would it somehow harm the functionality of VS?
I guess I could save my own snippets anywhere else. But if I would like to download a snippet from somewhere, would it fail due to the luck of the folder? Can't I configure a target folder for such downloads?

Comment: The subfolder should be safe to remove.  If you would like to configure it to be elsewhere take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478406/how-to-move-visual-studios-my-code-snippets-folder-to-another-drive/30071690

Comment: Thanks @JG that answers my question.