# Change where VS 2012 keeps the Visual Studio 2012 folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, directory

I am running visual studio 2012 on my windows 8 laptop, and I want to move the visual studio 2012 that holds the templates, projects, settings, etc in My Documents on a folder on my c: drive called Dev. When I copied the folder over to the Dev folder and deleted the original, an error message showed up when I ran vs again, and it created another visual studio 2012 folder in My Documents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change "Visual Studio 2010" folder location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395057/change-visual-studio-2010-folder-location)

Answer (score 1):

Click `Tools`>`Options` then `Projects and Solutions` change your `Projects location` path. There is a separate setting for project templates and item templates on the same screen.

Comment: Any windows registry sample about it? HKEY_LOCALMACHINE ?